# EditText's Hint doesn't work with arabic language in Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic, hint

when i launch my app in android device (4.0.4)
i don't see Arabic hint in `EditText`

activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/gradeInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="478dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/inputHint"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:targetApi="o" />
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="inputHint">تلميح</string>
```

i have read these answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210160/edittext-hint-doesnt-appear-in-arabic-on-galaxy-note-1-with-android-ics), but nothing has helped me :(

please help me...

Comment: have you change the phone default language?

Comment: It is showing the hint but it's end of the `Edittext`

Comment: @007 no, the device language is arabic

Comment: @ParthLotia i have this attribute in my .xml `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` is this affect ?

Comment: @uzx619 please update your full xml file...

Comment: It's because arabic is loaded in mirrored layout so all thing starts from left will start from right.

Comment: @uzx619 can you add screen shot of your screen?

Comment: @VrushiPatel ok, how do i make the `EditText`'s hint is from left for Arabic ?

Comment: @uzx619 right now you got hint in Ediitext? , or at the end of the Edittext?

Comment: You have to code for arabic language and set textaligment to `viewstart`.

Comment: @ParthLotia no, i don't see the hint in Arabic

Comment: @VrushiPatel i set the `android:textAligment="viewstart" but the IDE says you need to add `gravity` attribute to your xml and set value of gravity to "start", and nothing helped me :(

Comment: @uzx619 So add gravity to start :)

Comment: @VrushiPatel i added it to start but no differents :(

Comment: @uzx619 you used which version device JellyBean or Kitkat?

Comment: @ParthLotia android 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich

Comment: hello there, have you added manifest entry of support rtl in AndroidManifest.xml

`https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#supportsrtl`

Comment: @RahulKumar yes i added it. but i found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

to solve this problem, you need to delete `inputType` attribute and it's will work fine.

or you can do this :

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="none" />
```

But you cannot change the `inputType` attribute.

because if you changed it, the hint will be empty if the hint was arabic

Comment: Add this instrad of inputType as none
android:textAlignment="viewStart"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't know about your code but. You have to create a **Arabic String file** in android there you can use the hint in Arabic and there is one default String which is in English.
So while running your application change your phone language to Arabic. and your string will automatically work

add this line in manifest

```
   <application
        ...
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        ... >
    </application>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but.. the phone language is Arabic, and i have two strings.xml for arabic and english.

Comment: is your keyboard arabic or english??

Comment: ya input type if it is in english then it will come from left to right

Comment: or may be your current hint is in default xml

Comment: i already put this attribute `android:supportsRtl="true"` but nothing helps